# Custom date format

Tags: macros, boxes

I am trying to create a fancy date format as shown below:

[image]

The following is a MWE of what I have so far. For some reason or the other I can't seem to get the right height.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\dateboxheight}
\setlength{\dateboxheight}{%
    \heightof{%
        \parbox[b]{3em}{%
            May\\ %
            2014%
        }
    }
}
\newdateformat{squaredate}{%
\mbox{%
\resizebox{\dateboxheight}{!}{\THEDAY}~%
\parbox[b]{3em}{%
        \monthname[\THEMONTH]\\ %
        \THEYEAR%
}}}

\begin{document}
\squaredate\today
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions or improvements are welcomed. I know this can be done in TikZ; hence, I would consider it as a possible solution. Other improvement that are welcomed could be that the other months, like November, could be abbreviated so that they have the same width of May; that is, Nov. Probably an `\ifelse` case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are providing the incorrect height/width sizing in `\resizebox`. This is the appropriate interface: `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}`, so you should use

```
%...
\resizebox{!}{\dateboxheight}{\THEDAY}~%
%...
```

[image]

---

Here is something else to work with:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,datetime}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{datecolor}{black!40}
\colorlet{datebackground}{black!10}

\newdateformat{squaredate}{{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \cellcolor{datebackground} & \cellcolor{datebackground}\color{datecolor}\monthname[\THEMONTH] \\ %
    \cellcolor{datebackground}\smash{\color{datecolor}\resizebox{2.5\normalbaselineskip}{!}{\sffamily\THEDAY}} &
    \cellcolor{datebackground}\color{datecolor}\THEYEAR
  \end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}
\squaredate\today
\end{document}
```

Comment: How silly of me :-) I guess I was tired last night I didn't realize it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it. I have used `tikz` to achieve the goal. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\squaredate}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=lightgray] (-.1,-7) rectangle (-4.5,-5);
\draw (-3.5,-6) node {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont\bfseries  #1}; %%the two arguments to \fontsize are the actual font size and the size of the baseline-skip. The baseline-skip should be set to roughly 1.2x the font size.
\draw (-1.3,-5.5) node {\LARGE\bfseries #2};
\draw (-2.5,-6) -- (-0.2,-6);
\draw (-1.4,-6.5) node {\LARGE\bfseries #3};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\squaredate{20}{May}{2014}
\end{document}
```

I have defined a new command `squaredate`. It takes 3 arguments. The date, month and the year. And displays as per requirement.

Here is the output:

[image]